# Crashing when switching to cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I recently got new laptop (Dell XPS 15 9560) and I've bee having this issue where blender will crash when I try to select cycles as the render engine. I've tried reinstalling and rolling back my nvidia and integrated GPU drivers multiple times. Any suggestions or workarounds? I'm taking a course in blender later this year and I need my laptop for it.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more information about how exactly it crashes and when?

Comment: Does this also happen, if you deselect the GPU in User Preferences? Which Blender Version?

Comment: When I open the user settings window it will crash when I try to navigate to the system tab in the menu, so I am unable to change system devices through blender. With the 1050 disabled, blender will not open at all and will directly crash after the startup command prompt. It is version 2.79b running on wWndows 10. The crash happens when I go to the drop down menu at the top of the screen and switch to cycles. After I click cycles it will close all windows and no longer  show up in task manager. Also any existing blender files set to cycles will not open at all and crash on startup.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the error for me (taken from another thread): 
Turns out my WIndows Update was to blame, installing a .dll file that was breaking both Maya and Blender. This was called `igdrclneo64.dll`/`igdrcl64.dll`.  It’s located in `C:\Windows\System32` (On my computer it was located in `C: \ Windows \ System32 \ DriverStore \ FileRepository \ igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e.`) I moved it to the desktop and now everything works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for all the help. I ended up fixing it by removing some external display software. I had installed Duet Display and it was messing with my GPU settings. Hope this helps other people out.